# SimpleBlobDetector Class and Shape Descriptors differences in OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv, blob, shapes

As far as I understand from [opencv's documentation about contours](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html) there are a lot of useful methods in blob analysis (Specifically findContours, contourArea, etc.).

However [SimpleBlobDetector class](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/features2d/doc/common_interfaces_of_feature_detectors.html#simpleblobdetector) is also exist. How to use the two(contours and SimpleBlobDetector) together? Their aims looking same, aren't they? If there are differences what are those?